# How to determine if a FormGroup has a child control which is both INVALID and TOUCHED

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, formgroups

Speaking of [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms). I need to know if a [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) has a child [control](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) (not necessarily a direct child) which is both `invalid` and `touched` without having to traverse the whole `FormGroup`.

The problem is that the `FormGroup` itself is marked as `touched` as soon as **any** of its children is `touched`, and it is marked as `invalid` as soon as **any** of its children is `invalid`. But apparently, there is no easy way to get if (and only if) any of its children is both `invalid` AND `touched`.

In other words, I would like to achieve the following without needing to manually traverse the `FormGroup`:

```js
function traverseFormGroup(formGroup: FormGroup): boolean {
  let hasErrors = false;

  for (const key of Object.keys(formGroup)) {
    const child = formGroup.get(key);

    hasErrors = child instanceof FormGroup || child instanceof FormArray
      ? hasErrors || getFormValidationErrors(child)
      : hasErrors || !!child && child.errors !== null && child.touched;
    
    if (hasErrors) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return hasErrors;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you want to traverse the formGroup(s)?

Comment: @Sébastien as this looks quite a generic problem to solve, not application-specific, I was wondering if there was something like a built-in that exists in Angular

Answer (score 1):

```
validateAllFormFields(formGroup: FormGroup | FormArray) {
Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(field => {
  const control = formGroup.get(field);
  if (control instanceof FormControl) {
    control.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true });
    control.markAsDirty();
    control.updateValueAndValidity();
  } else if (control instanceof FormGroup || control instanceof FormArray) {
    this.validateAllFormFields(control);
    control.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true });
    control.markAsDirty();
    control.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
});
```

}

Comment: but this manually traversing the FormGroup like in the solution I showed...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).